# Objective C - Create a framework for my iphone apps?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, frameworks

I have created a set of model classes used by my iphone app.
I am trying to separate them into a new project and create a framework to make it reusable in my other projects?

Is this possible?

It looks like xcode only allows creating frameworks for Mac OS X. Any idea what type of project i should create to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build a static framework, ala [this article](http://blog.cloudmade.com/2010/05/10/iphone-static-framework/), or a static library. Personally, I typically opt for the static framework, just for my own ease of use.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's as easy as the article suggests to create a static framework. I haven't tried it's code, but I'm creating static frameworks for several libraries of mine and from the articles I read to get started, there is a lot more than that. For starters you need a Info.plist file which is not mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I Use static frameworks as well. I have some scripts you might find useful at https://github.com/drekka/dUsefulStuff. In the scripts directory there are separate scripts for assembling a static library and then creating a static framework. You can use those to see the steps you will need to go through. Scripting the whole process is the best method because you can integrate it into xcode or run it from the command.