# Customizing ios app for different clients

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have got my app approved on app store, now one of my client needs some extra features in the app,i am thinking of having a different code base for that client,but what if i have to customize app for more clients in future, in case of enhancements in actual code base, i will have to merge the changes from the actual code base to all other code bases(customized ones), it will be laborious.
Any help,suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do this at the company that I work at we use the same code base for all the different apps that we have and we can even brand them differently. We have written a branding system for this that does it based on the brand that is based into the app, so we can set different `text`, `colors`, `images` and then something that needs to be specific to a particle brand can be set in just that brand. So the best way to do this is to create a different target for each brand that you require (each target will be its own app) and make sure that the source is linked up correctly.

You could also create a framework that has all the shared code and then put all individual code in the app its self or add it to the framework still and just separate it into individual features such as have a class for `Login Process` a class for `Emailing` a class for `Printing` a class for `Storing data` and so on. Then if a client wants to have a feature that another client has then you already have the code and you just need to call it. This will save on development time, bug fixing and allow you to spend more time developing more features instead of fixing old ones. Also using SVN or GIT is a good way to store your code, and allow you to create your apps with ease. Such as you can create a trunk version of your framework and template app and create branches for incremental releases of your framework and each client you have with all there different brands. Source control is a very important when it comes to developing apps.

An example of how my company do it is that we have one project for one client then they have a target for each brand. So if we had ClientA and they wanted 3 different versions of the same app then we would create the project and call it something like ClientA and than have 3 targets called `Brand1`, `Brand2` and `Brand3` and then if a bug comes in for one of the apps (Targets) then you know that it is going to be in the others and you can fix it for all three apps by just fixing one issue.

This does have some issues though in that you can have a huge code base to maintain, but it will all be in one place so it is easier to maintain. If you have one bug in the code base it will be in every app, but it is only one fix instead of a fix for every app. And the final issue is that you would have to create the framework itself which can be quite complex, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465974/objective-c-create-a-framework-for-my-iphone-apps) may help.

I do believe all the pros of creating a framework outweigh the cons. So I would recommend creating a framework that all your apps are linked to. Also Have a look at creating a simpler system to CSS but for iPhones, or iPads or even Mac OSX. I have spent the last two months developing such a system that will allow it so apps can be branded (styled) very easily without actually having to know any objective-c, so currently we can add UIElements to our apps and set all the elements attributes without the developer interacting with any objective-c an all. The reason for this is that there are not that many people in our team that know objective-c as we are an internet development company not a mobile development company so alot of our team no CSS, also this can be done on a Windows computer then and built using our Mac Server which will then build the .ipa file and send it back to the developer so this also creates no need for an actual Mac.

Hope this helps a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [source control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) system, like SVN or GIT. I recommend Git as that can be used locally without a central repository and it's supported by Xcode.

Source control allows you to manage different versions of the same app very easily. In your case, you would check in the current version to the repository. Then you can create a branch to implement new features to a client. Later, you can then merge your changes to the main code base.

Answer (score 0):

Source control is a must have whatever you are trying to code, but in this case, it might not be very effective to maintain several code base for different features. The amount of conflicts you'll get when two code base become very different will be huge.

Depending on how heavy your features are, I would most probably go the 'Constant way'.

The idea is to have the same code for every one, but based on a constant, say the name of the client, show or hide these features. Before compiling and distributing you simply change the constant to the correct customer and voilà.

**Pseudo Code**

```
#define Customer = CUSTOMER_A

if (Customer in (CUSTOMER_A, CUSTOMER_B) {
  [self showButtonPickAContact]
}
```

**Upside**

- Only one code base
- Easy to maintain
- Adding an existing feature to an old client is easy
- Works very well for small sets of features like adding just a map for one customer

**Downside**

- The code base is bigger for everyone
- You can not use this system if one of the feature makes you include a 50 mb file for just one customer.
- Code and design are a little harder to write/design